# adding numbers that are products of primes

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

The title is rather moot, didn't find better words to describe it, so please bear with me...

Consider two integers

```
a = p1 * p2 * p3 .... * pn
b = p(n+1) * ... * pm
```

where `p1` till `pm` are distinct primes. Then none of this primes appears in the factorization of the sum of the two numbers, ie

```
mod((a + b), pi ) > 0    for all pi = p1....pm
```

I only stumbled upon this fact by chance and now I wonder: Is there some theorem about this? Does this property have a name?

Maybe this is just too trivial to be a theorem or even get a name, in that case, I'd be happy to get any pointers about where I can read more on it.

Comment: Note that with $m=n$ (i.e., $b=1$), this factlet is the main point in Euclid's historical proof that there are infinitely many primes

Comment: This is a slight generalization of an idea for proving there exists an infinite number of primes going back to Euclid.  One problem would be to ask which numbers can be expressed in the manner you suggest, and which of these are themselves primes.

Answer (score 2):

If $p_i\mid a+b$ and $p_i\mid a$ then $p_i\mid a+b-a=b$. Contradiction.

Comment: "where p1 till pm are **distinct** primes" .. maybe I should have been more clear on that

Comment: @user463035818 I saw that. My answer still holds.

Comment: (in fact, if the primes were not distinct, it wouldn't hold...)

Comment: sorry dont really get it. Have to take a break and maybe when Im back my brain works again ;)

Comment: i think you are actually giving a proof for my statement. You conclude that if pi is divisor of a+b and of a then it also divides b. This is not in contradiction to what I am saying, because I only consider a and b such that they do not have any common divisors and then I conclude that they also have no common divisors with their sum

Comment: proof by contradiction usually assumes the opposite of a statement.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee so the answer assumes the opposite of my statement and reaches a constradiction. q.e.d. :P

Comment: correct, this shows that the original statement being false is contradictory to the rules used in the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's true. It follows from the opposite of the distributive property of multiplication over subtraction (addition of negatives). That is, if $r\mid q=a+b$ and $r\mid a$ then $r\mid q-a=rc-rd=r(c-d)$ . More generally, if $r\mid q=a+b$ then a and b , are additive inverses (sum to 0) mod r. The property we used, is simply the case of them both having remainder 0.